# From a start-finish DateTime range, identify the number of hours that fall in 'normal hours' and 'after hours' ranges

Tags: apex

I have a tricky problem that i have been scratching my head with which i am hoping someone more knowledgable on apex might be able to assist with.

**Scenario:**

Our business operates a billing model that is dependant on the amount of time a technician spends onsite during the static time windows of

- 'normal hours' (08:00AM - 18:00PM)
- 'after hours' (18:00PM - 08:00AM)

We are given a **OnSite** DateTime and an **OffSite** DateTime.

**I need to identify the amount of time (in hours decimal) for **both** time windows for the spent onsite.**
.

Examples scenarios & expected results

---

**Includes only 'Normal Hours'**

> **OnSite DateTime** 2022-11-14 10:30 - **OffSite DateTime** 2022-11-14 14:30

> **NormalHours** = 4 (10:30 to 14:30)
> **AfterHours** = 0

---

**Includes morning 'After Hours'**

> **OnSite DateTime** 2022-11-14 06:30 - **OffSite DateTime** 2022-11-14 10:00

> **NormalHours** = 2 (8:00 to 10:00)
> **AfterHours** = 1.5  (6:30 to 8:00)

---

**Includes evening 'After Hours'**

> **OnSite DateTime** 2022-11-14 13:00 - **OffSite DateTime** 2022-11-14 21:30

> **NormalHours** = 5 (13:00 to 18:00)
> **AfterHours** = 3.5  (18:00 to 21:30)

---

**Includes BOTH morning and evening 'After Hours'**

> **OnSite DateTime** 2022-11-14 5:00 - **OffSite DateTime** 2022-11-14 21:30

> **NormalHours** = 10 (08:00 to 18:00)
> **AfterHours** = 6.5  (05:00 to 08:00) AND (18:00 to 21:30)

---

**Includes a rollover of days during the 'After Hours'**

> **OnSite DateTime** 2022-11-14 21:00 - **OffSite DateTime** 2022-11-15 02:00

> **NormalHours** = 0
> **AfterHours** = 5  (21:00 to 02:00)

---

Not expecting anyone to provide a complete solution (given the complexity), but if anyone has encountered a similar requirement or can shed some guidance on how to logically approach this it would be very appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part of it isn't working?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/874/124688
I tried this solution, and is so close; but doesn't seem to cater for the 'after hours' window to go across the 2 days (18:00 - 08:00)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a [BusinessHours](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_businesshours.htm) entry that specifies the correct start/end times, then use the diff method to determine the business hours:

```
BusinessHours standardHours = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours *some filter here*];
DateTime startTime; // set your start time
DateTime endTime; // set your end time
// This will be in milliseconds
Long businessDuration = BusinessHours.diff(startTime, endTime);
// This is also in milliseconds
Long totalDuration = endTime.getTime()-startTime.getTime();
Long afterHoursDuration = totalDuration-businessDuration;
// Note for partial hours, we need to divide by floating point
// Also, floating point will need to be rounded in some cases
Decimal totalBusinessHours = businessDuration/3600000.0;
Decimal totalAfterHours = afterHoursDuration/3600000.0;
```

Comment: Legend. I knew there would be some simple way to handle this. Testing it out now and everything seems to be working as expected